# Calling $timeout.flush() causes an Error: Unexpected request: **URL** No more request expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-promise

I'm currently testing my controller who makes two main things :

- Execute a JSONP request
- Execute a Service function which returns a promise

In order to start, i just test my Service Function `getTodaySpecials` but the problem is :

**i get this error : `Error: Unexpected request: **URL** No more request expected` when i call `$timeout.flush()` in my `it` block...**

I'm pretty new with Karma/Jasmine so i don't know if it's the right way ?

#### Controller :

```
angular.module('restaurant').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Menu', 'CONFIG', function ($scope, $http, Menu, CONFIG) {

    $scope.todaySpecials = [];
    $scope.pictures = [];

    var defaultsPictures = [
      {src: 'app/assets/images/pictures/4.jpg'},
      {src: 'app/assets/images/pictures/1.jpg'},
      {src: 'app/assets/images/pictures/6.jpg'}
    ];

    $http.jsonp(CONFIG.backendUrls.pictures + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
      .success(function (pictures) {

        if (!pictures || pictures.length <= 0) {
          $scope.pictures = defaultsPictures;
          return;
        }

        $scope.pictures = pictures;

      })
      .error(function () {

        $scope.pictures = defaultsPictures;

      });

    Menu.getTodaySpecials().then(function (todaySpecials) {
      $scope.todaySpecials = todaySpecials;
    });

  }]);
```

#### Test

```
describe('HomeCtrl', function () {

  var $scope, ctrl;
  var MenuMock;
  var pictures = [{src: 'something'}];

  beforeEach(function() {

    module('restaurant');

    MenuMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Menu', ['getTodaySpecials']);

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$timeout_, $q) {

      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      MenuMock.getTodaySpecials.and.returnValue($q.when(pictures));

      $timeout = _$timeout_;

      ctrl = $controller('HomeCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        Menu: MenuMock
      });

    });

  });

  it('should update todaySpecials asynchronously', function (){

    expect(MenuMock.getTodaySpecials).toHaveBeenCalled();  

    $timeout.flush();

    expect($scope.todaySpecials).toEqual(pictures);

  });

});
```

Comment: You are missing a $httpbackend expect

Comment: Something like $httpBackend
.expectGET('/example/url')
.respond(function (method, url, data, headers) {
    return [409, 'response body', {}, 'TestPhrase'];
});

Comment: So you mean i have to test everything in my controller ? I can't test separately my JSONP request and my Service Function ?

Comment: @RVandersteen I can't test separately my JSONP request and my Service Function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine Controller test: $timeout.flush() causes an 'Unexpected GET request' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711871/jasmine-controller-test-timeout-flush-causes-an-unexpected-get-request-err)